# Unable to re-enable ssh root login in CentOS

Tags: centos, root, scp, sshd

I need to be able to copy some files using `scp` as `root`, and for this I need to enable ssh login as `root`; so I edited the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by changing `PermitRootLogin no` to `PermitRootLogin yes`, and then I restarted `sshd` by issuing `service sshd restart`. However, the remote ssh login still doesn't work. The Linux distro is CentOS release 6.10 (Final). Does anyone know how to fix this?

The output of `ssh root@remote` says

> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password

When I enter the password (which is correct because it works when I
switch from another user to root—using `su`, not `sudo -i`, so this is using root's password—while connected to the server), it
says

> Permission denied, please try again.

Comment: How does it "not work"? Do you get an error message? What error? Can you establish a connection but not copy the files? Do you not establish a connection at all? Please [edit] your question and add the output of `ssh -vv root@remote` (where `remote` is the IP of the machine you are trying to connect to).

Comment: It says "debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password". When I enter the password (which is correct because it works when I swtich from another user to `root` while connected to the server), it says "Permission denied, please try again.".

Comment: When you say you switch from another user to root, what do you mean? `su`? Or `sudo -i`?

Comment: @terdon I mean `su`.

Comment: `ssh -vv` should be giving you a lot more output than that single line.